# How to capture message body from the SMSs received using Twilio?

Tags: sms, twilio

I'm am in the process of building an application wherein I would like to integrate Twilio SMS feature. The thing I would need in here is people would be sending messages to a "single mobile number (or a toll-free number)" and I would like to keep a track of mobile numbers from which I am getting the SMS messages as well as be able to read the content in them and apparently, store them in my database.

Moreover, I am using Salesforce or may go to php to build this application.

So, could you assist me by letting me know if there are APIs around Twilio to the above mentioned requirement.

Answer (score 2):

You need to have a callback url enabled on your server, and you need to parse the information received from Twilio when the callback url is called. You need to look for the `From` parameter, as [specified here](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/message).
Other API docs and a couple of examples can be found here:

- https://www.twilio.com/docs/quickstart/php/sms/hello-monkey
- https://www.twilio.com/docs/quickstart/php/sms/replying-to-sms-messages

Comment: Was wondering if we could actually track the mobile numbers (customers who are sending SMS messages) and the "message body" as well. So, that I could display the number and the message body in the web  portal or Salesforce.

Comment: Well, you do have both actually, just not in the same field.